# How to make query parameters in wiremock as optional parameters?

Tags: wiremock

How can I make query parameter(pageSize) in below json as optional while using wiremock

```
{
"request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/claims-search",        
    "queryParameters" : {
        
        "pageSize" : {
            "equalTo" : "10"
        },
        "pageNumber" : {
            "equalTo" : "2"
        }
    }       
},
"response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "response_200.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about what value the query parameters have, you can simply exclude them.

If you need them under certain circumstances, [you can use the Or operator to include an absent flag.](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#logical-and-and-or) In your case, it'd look something like...

```
{ 
    "request": { 
        "method": "GET", 
        "urlPath": "/claims-search",
        "queryParameters" : {
            "pageSize" : {
                "or": [{
                    "equalTo" : "10"
                }, {
                    "absent": true
                }]
            },
            "pageNumber" : {
                "or": [{
                    "equalTo" : "10"
                }, {
                    "absent": true
                }]
            }
        }       
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "bodyFileName": "response_200.json",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

I think this functionality was introduced in WireMock 2.29.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the query param is not then you can use

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.absent;

postRequestedFor(urlPathMatching("your Url Regex")).withQueryParam("pageSize", absent())
```

If you want to test the query param is present then we have couple of options

```
postRequestedFor(urlPathMatching("your Url Regex")).withQueryParam("pageSize", equalTo(10))
```

or matching against regex

```
postRequestedFor(urlPathMatching("your Url Regex")).withQueryParam("pageSize", matching("[0-9]+"))
```

If we have to match value only if exists and otherwise accept missing as well, then use or

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.or;

postRequestedFor(urlPathMatching("your Url Regex")).withQueryParam("pageSize", or(absent(),matching("[0-9]+")))
```